# Odd or even color for rowspan tablerow

Tags: jquery, html, css

odd/even styles set on table for each TD-element but don't work because of row span.
Try it on http://jsfiddle.net/eFp7F/61/

CSS style:

```
.tablerow1 td {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.tablerow2 td {
    background-color:green;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerow1">
        <td rowspan="1"><p>Cash</p></td>
        <td><p>Cash</p></td>
        <td><p>00000</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerow2">
        <td rowspan="2"><p>Receivables</p></td>
        <td><p>Receivable</p></td>
        <td><p>00</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Accounts</p></td>
        <td><p>0</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can be solve this?

Comment: You want accounts to be green as well?

Comment: what would you _like_ it to look like? Also do you want to use jquery or just css - if not remove the jquery tag

Comment: Styles work as they are set.

Comment: What did you expected?

Comment: your css is working exactly the way you have coded it to work. What you want?? give a sample picture

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "Accounts" and "0" cells should also be green. In this case, someone deleted the correct answer.

Comment: entire Receivables group should come in Green color.

Comment: @KishoreMohan Why don't you just add a class to your third tr tag (e.g tablerow3)? - http://jsfiddle.net/kfxm7tn2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to apply color alternatively.

```
.tablerow1 td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.tablerow2 td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try pseudo elements `:nth-of-type` [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HxwqA)

```
td:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:#666;
}
td:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `<td rowspan="2"><p>Receivables</p></td>` tag has class "tablerow2". 
Even if it is smeared over multiple rows, it still has that class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make it work with css in any case. You have to use JS to adjust your table.

If you are using jQuery, you can do it like that:

```
// each table cell with rowspan
$('table tr>*[rowspan]').each(function(){ 
  // get rowspan attribute
  let rowspan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
  // cast it to a useful numeric value
  rowspan = (typeof rowspan == 'string' || typeof rowspan == 'number') ? parseInt(rowspan): 1;
  // if 1 or below, no adjustments are necessary
  if (rowspan > 1) {
    // row of the affected cell
    let row = $(this).parent();
    // all silbing rows including the affected one
    let rows = row.parent().children();
    // index of the last potential row to be adjusted
    let indexlast = row.index()+rowspan-1;
    // for first row after rowspan to last one affected
    for (let i = row.index()+1; i<=indexlast; i++) {
      // if an affected sibling row has not the same modulo 2 index (equals odd and even or even and odd)
        if (row.index() % 2 != i % 2){
          // adds a class to reverse the logic
          rows.eq(i).addClass('reverse-even-odd');
        }
    }
    // only even numbered rowspans, to fix coloring on sequent elements
    if (rowspan % 2 == 0){
      // inserts a clearing row
      $('<tr class="clear-even-odd"></tr>').insertAfter(rows.eq(indexlast));
    }
  }
});
```

And the CSS:

```
table tr:nth-child(odd).reverse-even-odd,
table tr:nth-child(even){
background-color:#faa /* any color */
}
table tr:nth-child(even).reverse-even-odd,
table tr:nth-child(odd){
background-color:#aaf /* any color */
}
```

Please notice code is NOT optimized to work with multiple different rowspans a row - but that would kill the coloring anyways.

Please notice, that is made to remain the coloring of the field with the rowspan. All other cells of the affected row are displayed in the same color. But the same technic can be used to achieve different results.

Please notice that logic that is used to work with the table based on indexes or use sortings do not work that way and these logics have to be adjusted as well. However, such stuff often has to be customized to work on tables with merged cells.